Invalid XML tag
This is my sitemap xml file
https://swesshome.com/sitemap.xml
I had this error :
This tag was not recognised. Please fix it and resubmit.
Examples
Line 3
Parent tag:
urlset
Tag:
sitemap
Line 7
Parent tag:
urlset
Tag:
sitemap
Line 11
Parent tag:
urlset
Tag:
sitemap
Also
This required tag is missing. Please add it and resubmit.
Examples
Line 99
Parent tag:
urlset
Tag:
url
Can't identiy where is the problem  sitemap tags within the urlset parent tag. However, sitemap tags are not recognized within the urlset according to the sitemap protocol.
sitemap tags within the urlset parent tag. However, sitemap tags are not recognized within the urlset according to the sitemap protocol.
